# AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'cmap'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to visualize a dataset in python by matplotlib. I need points connected to each other by lines. I also have a colour pattern to show differences in changes. However, I need a coloured line instead of coloured points in 3D Plotter. Here is my code:

```
divnorm = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-3., vcenter=0, vmax=5)
    color_array = [get_color(v) for v in vario[1:200]]
    ax.plot3D(coordXList[:199], coordYList[:199], alt[1:200],c=color_array, cmap='RdYlBu_r') #, cmap='RdYlBu_r')
    im = ax.scatter3D(coordXList[:199], coordYList[:199], alt[1:200],
                      norm=divnorm, c=color_array, cmap='RdYlBu_r')


    ax.set_xlabel('X Axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Axis')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z Axis')

    ax.view_init(elev=10., azim=45)

    plt.show()

    Main()
```

I can visualize the data if use 'k' instead of `c=color_array, cmap='RdYlBu_r'`
but when I try to other cmap, I get

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/GPS reading/thermal line_PL (1).py", line 136, in <module>
    ax.plot3D(coordXList[:199], coordYList[:199], alt[1:200],c=color_array, cmap='RdYlBu_r' ) #, cmap='RdYlBu_r')
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 1471, in plot
    lines = super().plot(xs, ys, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1743, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 273, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 419, in _plot_args
    for j in range(max(ncx, ncy))]
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 419, in <listcomp>
    for j in range(max(ncx, ncy))]
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 312, in _makeline
    seg = mlines.Line2D(x, y, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 390, in __init__
    self.update(kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 996, in update
    raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} object "
AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'cmap'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Thanks

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: @DYZ thanks, I did.

Comment: See [this tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) to assign color to line segments.